# Prevent the user to write in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Sheetfile where I can add data through a form and a script assigned to a button.

Is it possible to add a GAS or JS to prevent the user to write data in the sheet without using the button ?

The purpose is to prevent the user to write on the sheet without preventing the script button. It uses a insertValues() function.

I made some researches and I found the Protection class.

I tried to do something but I don't really know if it's linked to the need.

```
// File used
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

// Sheet used
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var protection = sheet.protect();
protection.setDomainEdit(false);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "through a form and a script assigned to a button"? Is this form created using the HTML Service? Also please add a [mcve].

Comment: Can you clarify what "button" you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried controlling the access to the file and prevent anyone from writing to the file?